# Python - How to add two model fields in models.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a class in my models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.now)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    stock_in = models.IntegerField()
    stock_out = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    particulars = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Now I want to add some stocks in the balance. Using the stock_in values to add certain numbers to the balance of a specific product in the Inventory class. Using an UpdateView to it, so that I can just Update the stock_in field then adding that value to the balance.

I'm currently using this, I've tried couple of solution in the internet but to no avail.

```
@property
    def total(self):
        return self.stock_in + self.balance
```

Comment: Should `balance` denote the current stock, and `stock_[in|out]` the running totals of incoming and outgoing items? Such that: `balance == initial_balance + stock_in - stock_out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'official' mechanism in Django to do this. Recently, some ideas of adding some official solution to the Django framework were discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/ADSuUUuZp3Q/qV1Xqa_dCwAJ) on the django-developers mailing list. It might serve as an inspiration for what solution is currently best for your case.

Your method works well for simple calculations. If the property gets more expensive to calculate, using [`@cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) can help a bit if the value is used multiple times.

You can also rely on the database to compute these values by adding an annotation to the queryset. This requires defining a custom Manager:

```
class InventoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        super().get_queryset().annotate(total=F('stock_in') + F('balance'))

class Inventory(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.now)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    stock_in = models.IntegerField()
    stock_out = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    particulars = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    objects = InventoryManager()
```

This will add a `balance` attribute to your `Inventory` model instances if they are retreived using the default manager.

The problem with this approach (like discussed in the linked django-developers thread) is what your expectations are when modals are changed locally.

For example, with the custom manager in place, if I were to change `stock_in` for a modal, the value of `total` would still be valid for the value of `stock_in` at the time of retrieving it from the database:

```
>> qs = Inventory.objects.filter(date__gte=date(2017, 12, 22))
>> inventory0 = qs[0]
>> print(inventory0.total, inventory0.stock_in, inventory.balance)
100, 50, 50
>> inventory.balance = 100
>> print(inventory0.total, inventory0.stock_in, inventory.balance)
100, 50, 100
```

Also, an model instance not fetched from the db at all wont have a `total` attribute:

```
>> inventory = Inventory(stock_in=20, balance=10)
>> inventory.total
AttributeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute 'total'
```

Adding a `__getattr__` method to your class might be a solution to this usecase, but will still result in incorrect answers with local changes.